# Getting all strings that are one character off?

Tags: python, regex

If I have a word 'hungry' and I have a list like `['asdfd', 'hingry', 'hungre', ' hangrr']`

How can I get 'hingry' and 'hungre' since they are a character off? I thought about using regex, but I'm not so experienced in using it in python

Comment: Are "hungr" and "hungryx" also considered one character off?

Comment: No So I guess it should only be a change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` and `sum`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest as _zip
d = ['asdfd', 'hingry', 'hungre', ' hangrr']
word = 'hungry' 
results = [i for i in d if sum(a == b for a, b in _zip(i, word)) >= len(word)-1]
```

Output:

```
['hingry', 'hungre']
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name zip_longest, python 2.7.6

Comment: @lenik In old Python it was called `izip_longest`, but otherwise this code should work back to 2.5 or so (whenever itertools was added).

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

Once you install `python-levenshtein`, it's easy as:

```
>>> from Levenshtein import distance
>>> distance( 'hingry', 'hungry')
1
>>> distance( 'hungre', 'hungry')
1
>>> distance( 'hungr', 'hungry')
1
```

It automatically handles:

1. added characters
2. removed characters
3. replaced characters

The final code might look like this:

```
>>> words = ['asdfd', 'hingry', 'hungre', ' hangrr']
>>> [w for w in words if distance( 'hungry', w) < 2]
['hingry', 'hungre']
```

Comment: This is awesome, is there anyway to make it so the last one won't be counted? I guess I can set an if statement to make sure the lengths match